# match of javascript string for regular expressions is not tokenizing correctly

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to apply regular expression to the below string

```
Field "saveUserId" argument "idTwo" of type "String!" is required but not provided.
```

and have came up with a RegExp pattern such as this

```
var rePattern = new RegExp(/Field (.)+ argument (.)+ of type (.)+ is required but not provided./);
var arrMatches = e.message.match(rePattern);
console.log(arrMatches[0]);
console.log(arrMatches[1]);
```

am expecting arrMatches[0] to produce the output "saveUserId"
and arrMatches[1] to produce the output "idTwo".

However instead it is returning

```
arrMatches[0] = Field "saveUserId" argument "idTwo" of type "String!" is required but not provided.
arrMatches[1] = "
```

Comment: Put `+` after `.` inside `()`, `(.+)`. Better use lazy ones, `(.+?)`. And access the values with `arrMatches[1]` and `arrMatches[2]`

Comment: Use `(.+)` instead of `(.)+`. When repeating capturing groups, only the last time this group is matched is actually stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two problems :

1. `arrMatches[0]` contains the full match, the groups are accessible from `arrMatches[1]` to `arrMatches[1+n]`
2. Your capturing groups only contains 1 character : you want to include the quantifier inside the group to avoid only capturing the last character it matches ; use `(.+)` instead of `(.)+`

As [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/) mentions using lazy quantifiers would be an optimization as it would avoid backtracking : without it the `.+` will match as much as it can (reaching the end of the string), then backtrack until the next tokens can match, while with `.+?` the next token will be tested after each character `.` matches.
Note that this isn't an optimisation you can apply blindly ; I think a good rule of thumb is estimating whether the end of your match is closer to the end of the text, in which case backtracking will be more efficient - or to the start of the match, in which case lazy quantifier will be more efficient. It all boils down to the number of time the next token(s) will have to be tested.

A better optimization yet if your fields are guaranteed not to contain any `"` (escaped or not) would be to match them using the negated character class `[^"]` instead of `.`, which will make sure not to match further than the enclosing quotes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you confirm my explanation is correct?

Comment: Lazy quantifiers still cause something like backtracking, also referred to as "lazy pattern expansion" (@nhahtdh told me that). So, avoiding backtracking is not really the main differentiator. The main point is that `.+?` will match 1 symbol first, then the next subpattern will be tried, and if it is not matched, `.+?` will grab 2 symbols, and again the next subpattern will be tried, and so on until a match or no match. So, here, I think `.+?` lazy version should be preferred.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for your feedback, I've edited my answer to mention that backtracking shouldn't always be avoided. I've added a rule of thumb to estimate whether you'd better use lazy quantifiers or backtrack, further feedback is obviously welcome.

Comment: :) Both lazy and greedy quantifiers cost performance. Whenever possible, try to avoid both, or use in situations where they can do no harm. I'd use [`/Field "([^"]+)" argument "([^"]+)" of type "([^"]+)" is required but not provided\./`](https://regex101.com/r/N7QxbL/1) here.